# how to save R pie chart on disc as .jpg?

Tags: r, charts, save

Example of pie chart:

```
slices <- c(10, 12, 4, 16, 8) 
lbls <- c("US", "UK", "Australia", "Germany", "France")
pct <- round(slices/sum(slices)*100)
lbls <- paste(lbls, pct) # add percents to labels 
lbls <- paste(lbls,"%",sep="") # ad % to labels 
pie(slices,labels = lbls, col=rainbow(length(lbls)),main="Pie Chart of Countries") 

jpeg(filename="Pie chart.jpg",width=480,height=480)
plot()
dev.off()
```

Above code creates blank .jpg. What arguments should I write in plot()...if that is correct.

Comment: Never use pie charts.   Ever.   Read Ed. Tufte's books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the pie(...) line where plot() is now

```
jpeg(filename="Pie chart.jpg",width=480,height=480)
pie(slices,labels = lbls, col=rainbow(length(lbls)),main="Pie Chart of Countries") 
dev.off()
```